# TryAddWithoutValidation in HttpRequestMessage.Headers is normalizing my user agent when I do not want it to

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to add a User Agent string to my HttpRequestMessage but I am facing an issue that when I use TryAddWithoutValidation, my string still gets normalized and changed when I need to send that information as is.

```
requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("user-agent", "My App / 1.28.0");
```

And I need to send it this way, I know it is not RFC compliant etc... but if I do not send the string as is, the API doesn't respond and I have 0 control over the API.

What happens is that the request gets sent but without the spaces between My App and 1.28.0:

```
"My App/1.28.0"
```

Yes technically that is how a UserAgent should be formatted, but this is not what the API expects so I get 500. What can I do?

Thank you.

No Spaces in the debugger:
[image: User Agent Clearly without the spaces]
The constant with the User Agent and it clearly has spaces.
[image: Constant Holding the User Agent WITH spaces]
The Line where the User Agent is added:
[image: Line where I add the User Agent]
And Targeting .Net 5.
[image: Net5]

I had to use reflection to modify the private properties of the UserAgent object. It's not pretty but it works. If someone has a better way I am all for it.

Comment: just tried it and it works fine for me. Spaces are present. Ran through fiddler.

Comment: On what version of .net? I am trying on .net 5 and using HttpRequestMessage and it will just get rid of the spaces between App and the slash.

Comment: Did you watch the traffic in Fiddler? It may show that way in the debugger because `ToString` may do validation.

Comment: Yes I did, and no spaces.

Comment: Even got my blocked by the API because of it.

Comment: You're right -- It's broken in .NET5. It works great in .NETCore 3.1. I would open a bug on the github page. I'll see if i can figure out a kludge.

Comment: A way around it is to use reflection, ugly but works.

Comment: That's your only way out here. No idea what you'd override though.

Comment: I got it to work with reflection, what it does is it overrides the private fields that are no longer parsed or checked by the framework, just used as is, since it seems validation and parsing of the User Agent happens in the constructing of the User Agent object. I will post it as an answer so that if people need they know how to do it.

Comment: @E.Morell Did you ever post your solution?

Comment: @Alexis I never posted my code but here is the pastebin with it: https://pastebin.com/uZqKYYBY, I do what I mentioned above. It's not very pretty but it worked for me at the time to workaround their bug. I don't know if they ever fixed it.

Comment: @E.Morell Thank you, appreciate the reply.